# Want to display on specific items in list

Tags: c#, wpf

```
        if (DataList.Any(item => item.ID == int.Parse(Txtbox2.Text)))
        {
            Txtbox1.Text += string.Join(";", DataList.Select(o => o.DataString()));
        }
```

I am trying to get the list into a textblock but only the items that meet a certain criteria. 
The only thing I have is it displaying the whole list when the IF is met, is the any way for me to put a condition in the part that actually makes the list?

EDIT: all the DataString method is, is a method in the Data Class that converts all the vairous data types into a string output.

Comment: Where is the code that makes your list?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Where`, rather than `Any`:

```
int value = int.Parse(Txtbox2.Text); //consider using TryParse here
var strings = DataList.Where(item => item.ID == value)
    .Select(item => item.DataString());

Txtbox1.Text += string.Join(";", strings);
```

Also note that rather than parsing the textbox value over and over again, it's worth parsing it once and storing the result in a variable.